# Integrating a parameter inside a SSRS lookup expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am attempting to control the visibility of an error message with the following code:

```
=IIf((Lookup(Parameters!FA.Value, Fields!fa_num.Value,Fields!LastName.Value,"Advisor_Numbers")=""),False, True)
```

What this theoretically should do is look at the FA # inputted by the user, then look within the "Advisor_Numbers" dataset for a match in fa_num...and once found to check if the last name of the advisor is empty. 
If this is true: return false. Otherwise, return true.

This code always returns false despite the sample FA numbers I use existing in the Advisor_Numbers table. Is my syntax for writing a parameter within a lookup incorrect?

Ideally I'd just like to lookup if the parameter exists within the table without involving the last name.

Comment: Expr looks fine. For troubleshooting, put the value of FA, fa_num and LastName in seperate textboxes and see what you get. Based on that you might be able to identify your problem.

Comment: All 3 returned back values. The first returns the FA parameter. Since the second and third contain multiple values I just selected the text to show the first of each. The FA parameter matched the first fa_num...

Comment: Do you have multiple records with the same FA_Num? Lookup stops when it finds the first one.

Comment: No I didn't have multiple records with the same fa_num...just empty space in the data that caused all my lookups to come back empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my own problem.

While everything looked fine on the surface, there was probably some empty space somewhere in my data. Therefore, make sure to use Trim.

```
=IIf((Lookup(Trim(Parameters!FA.Value),Trim( Fields!fa_num.Value),Trim(Fields!LastName.Value),"Advisor_Numbers")=""),False, True)
```

The code above worked smoothly and solved all my issues